# Visual Force page Error - No record to save

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a master record (Time_sheet__c) and child records (Time_sheet_items__c).
I have made a VF page that displays child records in a editable table. however at the moment I cannot filter the VF data so that it only pulls the child records related to master records the page triggered from (time_sheet__c.id = Time_sheet_item__C.Time_sheet_id__C).

I tried changing the VF page so it triggered from the master records rather than the child records list buttons. This works in that the table is now filtered but i cannot save changes made to the filtered child records table and get the below error:

> Error: There is no record to save

HELP!

**Controller:**

```
public class EditAllButtonForTimeSheetController {

    public EditAllButtonForTimeSheetController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {

    }

  public String TSRecordId        {get; set;}

  public List<Time_Sheet_Items__c> getTimeSheetRecords()
     {

       //Sets Time Shet id to variable
       TSRecordId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');

        // this query needs a where clause, don't leave it unbounded
        List<Time_sheet_Items__C> TimeSheetRecords = 
         [SELECT Id,
            Time_Sheet__c,
            D_Type__c,
            D_Product_manager__c,
            D_Project__c,
            Day_Monday__c,
            Day_Tuesday__c,
            Day_Wednesday__c,
            Day_Thursday__c,
            Day_Friday__c,
            Day_Weekend__c
       FROM Time_Sheet_Items__c 
       WHERE Time_sheet__c = :TSRecordId  ];
    return TimeSheetRecords;
    }
}
```

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Time_Sheet__c"
         Extensions="EditAllButtonForTimeSheetController">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageMessages />
      <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandButton value="Save"
                            action="{!save}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!TimeSheetRecords}"
                           var="TSi">
        <apex:column style="width:5%" value="{!TSi.D_Project__c}"/>
        <apex:column style="width:5%" value="{!TSi.D_Type__c}"/>
        <apex:column style="width:5%" value="{!TSi.D_Product_Manager__c}"/>
    <apex:column style="width:5%" headerValue="Monday">
          <apex:inputField value="{!TSi.Day_Monday__c}"/>
        </apex:column>
    <apex:column style="width:5%" headerValue="Tuesday">
          <apex:inputField value="{!TSi.Day_Tuesday__c}"/>
        </apex:column>
    <apex:column style="width:5%" headerValue="Wednesday">
          <apex:inputField value="{!TSi.Day_Wednesday__c}"/>
        </apex:column>
    <apex:column style="width:5%" headerValue="Thursday">
          <apex:inputField value="{!TSi.Day_Thursday__c}"/>
        </apex:column>
    <apex:column style="width:5%" headerValue="Friday">
          <apex:inputField value="{!TSi.Day_Friday__c}"/>
        </apex:column>
    <apex:column style="width:5%" headerValue="Weekend">
          <apex:inputField value="{!TSi.Day_Weekend__c}"/>
        </apex:column>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>     
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Where is the `save` method in your controller ?

Comment: It's defined in the `StandardController`. That should be sufficient to prevent errors (though not to actually save any child records).

Comment: Hi Adrian, how to I get the visual force page to save changes to the child records?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the standard controller Save method which works on the Master Object record from which the request was originated and thus it is giving this error.

You need to write a custom save method in your extension controller like this where you will update the child list records.

```
public pageReference save(){
    update lstChildRecords; // Child List which you will retrieve for the given Master Record
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi Devendra I have tried to add this but I get an error with the variable not existing if i use the below:  
// adds a custome save button to the VF page to save the child recrods not the master ID
     public pageReference save(){
    update List<Time_Sheet_Items__c>; // Child List which you will retrieve for the given Master Record
    return null;
 }